# How does internal links on Twitter work?

Tags: javascript, html

When you click on twitter.com on the tab Following for example no new page is loaded, only a ajax request is done to receive some JSON and the tab is showed. Also the url in the address bar is changed.

But then if you enter http://twitter.com/#!/yourusername/following in your address bar the following tab is showed. How does this work exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Ajax" is used to grab new content and that is appended to the page. `location.hash` is manipulated after each request/internal link.

Github uses a more advanced technique by manipulating `history.pushState` which doesn't require changes to the hash.

Of course, it's possible twitter uses the `history.pushState` to change the url including the hash but I don't think they are using it.

Comment: ok thanks, so if I understand well the location.hash is checked on a page load to see for which tab a ajax request has to be done?